# Is there any R function to swap rows for a category type data?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which roughly looks likes:

```
X   Cat     Nam    Val
1   Total  Total   102012
2   Car     A       12312
3   Car     B       22222
4   Car     Total   34534
5   Bike    C       1000
6   Bike    Total   1000
```

What I want it to look like is:

```
X   Cat     Nam    Val
1   Car    Total   34534
2   Car     A       12312
3   Car     B       22222
4   Bike   Total   1000
5   Bike    C       1000
6   Total  Total   102012
```

Is there a simpler way to do this rearranging depending there may be many more categories?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign factor levels based on the order you want the data in.

For example, in `Cat` column you want `'Total'` value to go last so keep it at the end in `levels` and rest of them at the beggining. In `Nam` column you want `Total` to be first so keep it first. After arranging the factor levels you can `order` the data on those 2 columns.

Using base R, you can do this as :

```
df <- transform(df, 
            Cat = factor(Cat, levels = unique(c(Cat[Cat != 'Total'], 'Total'))), 
            Nam = factor(Nam, levels = unique(c('Total', Nam))))

df[with(df, order(Cat, Nam)), ]

#  X   Cat   Nam    Val
#4 4   Car Total  34534
#2 2   Car     A  12312
#3 3   Car     B  22222
#6 6  Bike Total   1000
#5 5  Bike     C   1000
#1 1 Total Total 102012
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use a logical vector to `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    arrange(Cat == 'Total', Cat, Nam != 'Total')
```

---

If the 'Cat' values needs to be in the same order

```
df1 %>%
  arrange(Cat == 'Total', 
         factor(Cat, levels = c(setdiff(unique(Cat), 'Total'), 'Total')),
         Nam != 'Total') %>%
   mutate(X = row_number()) -> out
```

-output

```
out
#  X   Cat   Nam    Val
#1 1   Car Total  34534
#2 2   Car     A  12312
#3 3   Car     B  22222
#4 4  Bike Total   1000
#5 5  Bike     C   1000
#6 6 Total Total 102012
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = 1:6, Cat = c("Total", "Car", "Car", "Car", 
"Bike", "Bike"), Nam = c("Total", "A", "B", "Total", "C", "Total"
), Val = c(102012L, 12312L, 22222L, 34534L, 1000L, 1000L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```